# unwrap cube with circle

Tags: extrude

[image]
make cube, draw circle and extrude in. while unwrap the cube, it did't unwrap perfectly. its unwrap like what in the picture.[image]

Comment: What is your question, this is how your object unwraps. What result do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having are three N-Gons. N-Gons are faces with more than 4 verts. So you need to change the N-Gons to tris or quads. To triangulate a face, just press SPACE and type triangulate, you will then see the option "triangulate faces".

The first picture shows my unwrap with N-Gons, the second one is with triangles.

[image]
[image]

However, the right way of doing it (if you want to maybe use sub-d or something) would be like this. You the only would have to deal with the edges going over the cube.:

[image]

Comment: Go up with this, especially for last example. Some loop cuts trough the mesh would be a good idea to keep quads more square-like. But overall, OP go with this method. It's important to keep topology clean and quad.

Comment: Yes, also thought about this. However, i didn't want to do a post about topo in generell, because that#s a whole topic on it's own^^

Comment: It's really important to encourage users to use proper topology, sadly many of answers don't take this as an value creating more issues later on.

Comment: These are the users, which will never reach a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all faces without N-gons and U unwrap them, then select the face with the hole in front ortographic view and press U "project from view, then adjust the size of the UV islands.[image]